# How to map a virtual network drive to specific location

Tags: windows, network-drive

My client is using a customized accounting software that uses Visual Fox Pro as its DBC.

The software is located at `C:\USER\c\FOLDER`. 
This folder is mapped to `Z:` but I see some of the scripts referring to the `\\USER\FOLDER` location.

When I tried to map the folder again, I could only map it to `\\USER\c\FOLDER`. 
I want to drop the intermediate `c` folder in between. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Just share `C:\USER\c` as `\\USER`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I found a similar way as well:

1. Go to `FOLDER` directly, right-click, then go to `sharing` tab. Click `advanced` sharing, and check the `sharing` box. Steps varies depending on which windows version you are using, but the main idea is to mark the folder as for sharing.

2. Now `FOLDER` should appear as an option in the dropdown when mapping virtual network drive to a letter.